# MP4ファイルの読み込み

Tags: opencv, mp4

OpenCV3.1を使用して、ビデオファイルの読み込みをしています。

```
VideoCapture  video;
video.open("test.mp4");
```

上記のようにmp4ファイルを指定していますが、読み込みができません。
ファイルをAVIファイルに変えると読み込めます。

何が問題でしょうか？
宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: AVIでも読み込めるAVIと読み込めないAVIがありました。コーデックの問題でしょうか？

Comment: コーデックの問題に思えますね。リファレンスを見てもサポートしている形式についての記述が見当たらないので、内部実装に依存するとかでしょうか。プロパティに`CAP_PROP_FOURCC`,`CAP_PROP_FORMAT`などがあるのでそれでどうにかできませんか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

自己解決しました。。

opencv_ffmpeg310.dllを他のdll同様にexeと同一フォルダに配置したところ普通に読み込めました。